# access a website through a linux server

Tags: linux, networking, debian, localhost

Is there a way to forward the router dashboard to a local debian server?
the dashboard is on `192.168.1.1` and I would like to access via `serverip:port`, the server, which ports are open, is on the same network as the router.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Your question could use some clarification - What do you mean by *"router dashboard"*?  What router are you using?  Are you saying you want to use the Debian system as a proxy to the router for some reason?  The *why* isn't strictly necessary, but may be useful to help understand what you are really asking for and provide suggestions.

Comment: Sure, there are multiple ways one could accomplish this. To select an appropriate one, please provide more context. *Why* are you trying to do this? Is it perhaps about accessing it using a tunnel (SSH or VPN or otherwise)?

Comment: I think your question may be badly worded. Did you mean tjat you want to refer to a website on your LAN by using a domain rather then an IP address?  If so, how many computers on your LAN need to do this and do you know what router you are using?   What OS's do the computer(s) accessing the website run and do you have a domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking to do is setup a reverse proxy.
There are a few ways to accomplish this, given your server is linux:

- iptables proxy forward
- haproxy
- nginx or apache proxy

I will cover nginx only.

On the server, you would create a configuration under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

myproxy.conf

```
server {
 listen 8888;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1
 }
}
```

or, if your router dashboard is running on https, you would have `proxy_pass https://192.168.1.1`

You would then go to serverip:8888 to get to your router.

Your router may simply not accept forward traffic like this.You may need to set headers.see also: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: I suspect the question is badly worded and all tjats neccessary is to handle the DNS/IP lookup/resolution, without needing a reverse proxy.

Comment: @davidgo nope, that's exactly what I needed